# How to reload a window after window open if content is coming dynamic?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a **project** where I create some element in **javascript** and assign a `variable` and when I click a button than opens a `window` and write variable value in my new `window` and then I need to reload my `window` but if i `reload` my `window` then variable written is not shown in my new `window`. How to achieve this?

**My code is this**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#preview').click(function() {
    var newForm = "<h2>Rohit Azad</h2>"; // here coming variable data 
    var myWindow = window.open('', " form preview", "width=200, height=400", '_blank');
    myWindow.document.write(newForm);
    myWindow.location.reload();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="preview">CLick here</button>
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dqss4fuL/2/)**

In above fiddle if you click on button a new window will open and my variable is written there but when I reload it using `myWindow.location.reload();`, the variable disappears.

Comment: Try add `window.opener.location.reload();` instead of `myWindow.location.reload();`

Comment: Here's **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/dqss4fuL/5/)** for @Alexander's workaround.. :)

Comment: Do this but text is not coming chech to my fiddle

Comment: Do you have to use `document.write()`? There shouldn't be any good reason to use it these days.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
;
    $('#preview').click(function(){
        var newForm = "<h2>Rohit Azad</h2>";
        var myWindow = window.open('', " form preview", "width=200, height=400", '_blank');
        myWindow.document.write(newForm);
        myWindow.opener.location.reload();
    });


});
```

The opener property returns a reference to the window that created the window.
even When opening a window with the window.open() method, you can use this property from the destination window to return details of the source (parent) window. see: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp

js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dqss4fuL/6/

Comment: Hi @YPS Thanks for give me answer but i click to button than reload only parent window not reload popup window .

Answer (score -1):

To reload the window , you may use

```
myWindow.location.href=myWindow.location.href;
```